# Creating a hosted XE6 environment

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, delphi-xe, aws-opsworks

We have a large codebase and use XE6 to compile it into an .exe file for installation on our clients machines.

Currently engineer  has his / her own local instance of XE6 on their machine. When we need a client update, they pull from the GIT and then run XE6 to create the executable.

The issue is that some of our machines are not very powerful, so it can take a long time to create an install file. We have read a little bit about hosting environments (EC2 in particular) and we are considering creating a virtual environment to run our compilation process, which will speed things up, and reduce the downtime on peoples machines.

Delphi / Embarcadero have a lot of content on deploying apps to the 'cloud' but I cannot locate anything of actually using hosted processing power to run their applications. We really want to understand if they can be configured easily on a EC2 instance, or will it require significant effort?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in "the cloud", rather than setting up a build server of your own? I'm not sure what benefit a hosting environment would provide, other than slowing down the entire process. Do you have engineers doing one-off builds and sending directly to the client or posting for download? Delphi licensing includes a license for deploying a command-line compiler to a build server, but licensing questions related to anything other than that should be addressed to Embarcadero instead of here; this isn't a legal advice or licensing interpretation site.

Comment: Just for the record: I'm not the one that downvoted this question, although I did cast a close vote for being too broad. I don't think the question is poorly written, just that it's very wide in scope and also that it asks for legal advice related to licensing that should be addressed to either EMBT or your attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Delphi build server is easy to set up and configure (I have done it many times). While I prefer the Delphi command line compiler and [Ant build scripts](http://ant.apache.org/), invoking MSBuild and the project file is also a way to run the build.

Either way, a new build of the application can be started from the command line and execute the whole toolchain.

With build servers (Hudson/[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for example), running the build can be triggered manually or automatically whenever a source control commit happens.

Using a Amazon EC2 Windows AMI it can be done in the cloud, obviously. (However I would prefer a in-house solution, using a central build server, optionally running in a virtual machine).